# I want to graph errors over a duration of time in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have hundreds of computers at my workplace that I monitor. Sometimes these computers are bound to fail. I want to be able to write down the date and the computer that failed, and to be able to see the trends over time.

The overall goal is to see where the problematic computers are and quarantine them. What is the best way to go about doing that in excel or google sheets?

Comment: Do you have any progress so far? Are you trying to automate the data collection or would you be entering errors manually? If the latter, it should be as simple as setting up a sheet and adding any types of charts or formulas that you want.

Comment: Please would you provide more specific details about your problem. Are you trying to read some logs file(s) and then to create a report in Google Sheet?, if that is the case, please provide sample log file and the expected output you would like to see in your Sheet.

Comment: I am trying to track a single variable (computers that are failing) and seeing how often it occurs a pool of computers. Then I would like to be able have those failures tracked over a duration of time. Trying to manipulate a set of data and make it into a more accessible and digestible so we can take action more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a new spreadsheet (I recommend Google Sheets, since it will allow more flexibility with future implementations such as feeding results to the spreadsheet with forms, etc.).

Name the first sheet something simple yet descriptive (perhaps "FailureLog").

Include at least the following headers:

• in A1: `Date`
• in B1: `Computer ID`

That is all you really need, though you may also want additional columns, e.g.:

• in C1: `Location`
• in D1: `Error Type`

Then just add your data under the appropriate headers. From that, any number of reports can be generated. The first step is to get data entered in a meaningful and consistent way.

By consistent, it is very important that you enter Computer IDs in exactly the same way each time. You can't call the same computer `X001`, `X-001` and `X1` or it will be seen as three different computers.

Once you do the above — setting up a sheet, deciding which fields to include, and gathering some data — create a new post, sharing a link to that spreadsheet, and contributors here will be able to use that to suggest some report formulas for you.

If you want, you could even enter some realistic dummy data into the spreadsheet and post the link back here. With that, contributors here could make suggestions on error controls, formatting, data validation (to prevent errors in the first place), etc.

We just have to have something to start with.